# how to render multiple textures with GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

i am about to port all my rendering from "old" opengl to glsl.

now i have a mesh with different textures, so in "old" gl i just used bindTexture to change the texture. i guess, i still need to do this, but something is missing, since my everything seems to be rendered with the first texture only.

```
uniform sampler2D tex;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = tex2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
}
```

"tex" is the name of the texture which i put to glsl like this:

```
int loc = glGetUniformLocationARB(id, "tex");
glUniform1iARB(loc, 0);
```

note: i am not talking about multitexturing! :-)

Comment: So if my previous answer was wrong, could you maybe show us some more of your C code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have bound texture unit 0 to the `sampler2D`, but you need to bind the texture to the texture unit as well. So that'd be simply a `glBindTexture` call.

Comment: thanks, yepp, as i said i am still doing the glBindTexture call, but even though i bind a different texture at a specific time, i still see the object with the previous texture.

Comment: glBindTexture is the call that changes what is bound. If that does not work for you, it either means your call to glBindTexture is wrong, or you are modifying a different texture unit (e.g. because you called glActiveTexture and forgot to reset the active texture unit to 0).

Comment: bahbar: thanks, that was it! i accidentally had another texture unit active!

Answer (score 5):

i was confused with the way to tell GLSL which texture unit to use for which sampler as well.
i searched hours for my problem and could not solve it because i think this topic is not very well explained in all the literature out there.

here is a valuable explaination: (see the part "Using Textures With GLSL")
http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/articles/article.asp?article=21

maybe this helps somebody!